# Is it possible to use different view resolvers?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, birt

I have multiple view resolvers in a Spring configuration and wanted to use different view resolvers for different requests.

Example: For URLs starting with `report_*`, use Birt view resolver, and for ajax calls use Tiles resolver and so on.

Tried setting order property, but all views are resolved by `tilesViewResolver`.

```
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="com.example.example.util.AjaxTiles21View"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="birtViewResolver" class="org.eclipse.birt.spring.core.BirtViewResolver">
    ...
    <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="beanNameResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You absolutely can. `ViewResolver` has a single method, [`resolveViewName(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html#resolveViewName-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) which returns

> the View object, or **null if not found** (optional, to allow for ViewResolver chaining)

Your `ViewResolver` beans are registered. When a view name is returned by a handler, Spring will iterate through each `ViewResolver`, invoking their `resolveViewName` method with the given name. If the method returns non`-null`, that `View` is used. If `null` is returned, then it continues iterating.

So the implementation has to return `null` if Spring is to skip it.

There are some implementations that never return `null`. This seems to be the case with your custom `ViewResolver` classes. If the `ViewResolver` returns a `View`, even if that `View` will eventually fail to be rendered, Spring will use it.

You either need to fix that or order your `ViewResolver` beans. For example, you can order them with the `Ordered` interface. Have your classes implement that interface and return an appropriate value.

Comment: how did you call it in your controller (assuming you are using controller)?

Comment: this is my controller `@RequestMapping(value = {"/report_emp"}) public String reportTest(Model model) {return null;}`

Comment: @tangobee Just FYI: the `@name` thing works more reliably if you remove the spaces, e.g. `@SotiriosDelimanolis`. In this case, it didn't matter, as you don't need the `@name` if you are responding to the person who left the answer. In most cases, the software would have tried to guess who you meant based on who had responded, as it would have ignored the "Delimanolis" part since it came after a space. At least, that's the way I understand it.

Comment: @trl the first three letters of the name are sufficient.

Comment: @mhm If they are unambiguous. Honestly, I just type @, start tying, and when I see only one name, I press tab.